# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to3}\frac{e^{-1\over(3-x)^2}+e(4-3\cos(x-3))^{1/5}-e^{\sqrt {4-x}}}{\sqrt {1-\cos(x-3)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

First of all, I make the substitution $x-3=t$ which gives me: $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^{-1\over t^2}+e(4-3\cos t)^{1/5}-e^{\sqrt {1-t}}}{\sqrt {1-\cos t}}$$
The term $e^{-1\over t^2}$ goes to $0$ as $t$ approaches $0$ so I ignore it and $e^{\sqrt {1-t}}$ is just $e$, so I have to work on remaining two terms.
The term in the denominator becomes ${t\over \sqrt2}$ as we replace $\cos t$ by $1-{t^2\over2}$. Applying the same to remaining term yields  $e(1+{3t^2\over2})^{1/5}=e(1+{3t^2\over10})$. So we have: $$\lim_{t\to0}{e+{e3t^2\over10}-e\over{t\over\sqrt 2}}$$
Which should equal to $0$, but apparently the correct answer is ${-e\over\sqrt2}$. So where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Depends, are you evaluating the limit from the right or left? Because as written, this limit does not exist. 

Also, the assertion you make with $e(1+{3t^2\over2})^{1/5}=e(1+{3t^2\over10})$ is not true.

Comment: @Denis28  am evaluating limit just for $x\to3$ not left or right.There's a possibility that the answer $({-e\over\sqrt 2})$ is flawed,but how doesn't the limit exist?

Comment: when evaluating the limit as $x\to3^+$ and $x\to3^- $you obtain different answers, thus the limit does not exist.

Comment: Then,something must be wrong with question,i guess.

Comment: The first term in numerator can be ignored but not because it tends to $0$ but because the term divided by denominator tends to $0$. In effect one is splitting the given expression into a sum of two fractions where the first fraction uses $e^{-1/(3-x)^2}$ as numerator and this fraction tends to $0$. It is best to apply algebra of limits rather than ignore terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the limit  $$\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{(3-x)^2}}+e(4-3\cos(x-3))^{1/5}-e^{\sqrt {4-x}}}{\sqrt {1-\cos(x-3)}}\to{\small{\begin{bmatrix}
&t=x-3&\\
&t\to0^-&
\end{bmatrix}}}\to\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}+e(4-3\cos t)^{1/5}-e^{\sqrt {1-t}}}{\sqrt {1-\cos t}}$$

And, as you mentioned it is enough to consider the limit
$$\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{e(4-3\cos t)^{1/5}-e^{\sqrt {1-t}}}{\sqrt {1-\cos t}}.$$

Using Taylor Series, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
&(4-3\cos t)^{1/5}\sim 1+\frac{3 t^2}{10}+\cdots \\
&e^{\sqrt{1-t}}\sim e-\frac{e t}{2}+\cdots\\
&\cos(t)\sim1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots
\end{aligned}$$
and substituting (and noting that the asymptotic terms $\to0$ as $t\to0$) we have
$$\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{e+\frac{3et^2}{10}-e+\frac{e t}{2}}{\frac{\vert t\vert}{\sqrt{2}}}=-\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{\frac{3et}{10}+\frac{e}{2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=-\frac{e}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

---

It is clear, from this last expression, that since there is a $\vert t\vert$ in the denominator the limit will not exist because $x\to3^+\implies t\to0^+\implies \vert t\vert=t$.

Comment: Thank you very much.So what was missing on my work was using taylor expansions of $e^{\sqrt(1-t)}$.But how could i know that the answer i obtained $(0)$ was incorrect and that i should have expanded $e^{\sqrt(1-t)}$?

Comment: Generally, you should expand each term up to the same order, in this case order $2$. You did not do such thing with $\exp(\sqrt{1-t})$

Comment: I didn't know that,thanks a lot.